# Unable to display additional json data sent from laravel controller after dropzone file upload success

Tags: laravel-5.3, dropzone.js

I'm trying to add custom success message and additional data from a laravel controller using json data type after a successful dropzone js file uploaded and send it back as dropzone js success event to client.

If I write my **laravel controller** like this:

`return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'message' => 'custom success message!', 'additional' => 'info'), 200);`

and call the response in **my client** like this:

```
<script>
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var myDrop = new Dropzone("div#divdropzone", {

            //..edited the rest of the script..

            init: function() {
                this.on("success", function(file, response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

It will give this error in my browser console log:

> Invalid JSON response from server.

If I remove the *return response()->json* from my laravel controller (without returning anything), this is the *console.log(response);*

> ca0ba5acc1c71f922278ea9f6ad7fa4e.jpeg
> jpg
> C:\Windows\Temp\php83D1.tmp

FYI, the file upload works fine and accordingly with or without the

**return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'message' => 'custom success message!', 'additional' => 'info'), 200);**

What I'm trying to do with the json response from the server is to view my success message along with the additional data into the client's console.log() so I can further process the response for example:

```
init: function() {
    this.on("success", function(file, response) {
        console.log(response.message);
        console.log(response.success);
        console.log(response.additional);
    });
}
```

I still cant figure it out how my server's json data communicate with dropzone on("success") response parameter.
Kindly help me point the mistake in my laravel controller or in my client dropzone script. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I am currently stuck with the exact same issue here. Currently trying to figure it out, once I know I'll post solution here. From my initial looks it has nothing to do with how we respond from the laravel side of things as that reply is valid, just how dropzone seems to receive and handle it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just whipped something up and got it working. This is **Laravel 5.4.23** and latest **dropzone.js**
My problem was basically that I had still a `DIEDUMP (dd)` inside the controller to do some debugging.

Controller / ImageHandler

```
// whatever logic here
return response()->json(['success' => true, 'payload' => 'My message']);
```

Then inside my JS :

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    uploadMultiple: false,
    parallelUploads: true,
    maxFilesize: "{{ dsoptions.maxfilesize }}",
    // whatever other options you got here
    init:function() {
        // .on event handlers see dropzone docs for info
    },
    error:function(file, response) {
        // error handling
    },
    success:function(file, response) {
        console.log(response.payload);
    }
}
```

As easy as this. So if, say, success in my response was false, I could now check for that and adjust the message in dropzone success function accordingly.

Comment: Wow, I almost forgot about this issue since I decided to accept dropzone.js without any custom message parameters. Thanks a ton @privilegue ! Answer accepted.